# DefaultModelBinder substitute in dotnet core

Tags: .net, model-binding, android-binder

I used DefaultModelBinder in my ASP.NET MVC project. It worked as a default binder mechanism if a custom one didn't work. Now I'm rewriting the project to dotnet core and DefaultModelBinder does not exist here.

I want to map the following URLs to the same SearchModel.

1. http://address.com/test/?query=term1
2. http://address.com/test/?ask-term1

```
public class SearchModel
{
    [BindProperty(Name ="q")]
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
}
```

My custom binder will map case 2) and for case 1) I would like to trigger the default binder in my custom binder. Perhaps  I should use *QueryStringValueProvider*, but I don't know how to do that.